# Assembly file structure when building a project (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If someone could clarify the following, with regards to c#, this would be great.

Say I have a web project (`webproj1`) and a class library (`classlib1`).

`webproj1` has a reference to `classlib1`.

`classlib1` also has a reference to a third party dll (`thirdpartydll`).

When built, the `\bin` folder of `webproj` will obviously contain `classlib1.dll`, but should it also contain a copy of `thirdpartydll.dll`(which is referenced from `classlib1`) or is it somehow 'embedded' in to `classlib1.dll`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need it separately when the assembly cannot be found in for example the GAC.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx

You could embed it using ILMerge (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx)

Comment: Shouldnt visual studio copy `thirdparty.dll` into `webproj1`'s `\bin` folder?

Comment: When Copy Local on the reference is set to true, yes.

Comment: Hmm well one problematic dll seems to be copied to the \bin folder of the class library but not the \bin folder of the web project

Comment: Then add the third party assembly to the references of the web project.

Comment: It seems some assemblies are copied into the \bin of the web project but some arent. Is there any logic to this?

Comment: Yes, secondary assemblies that are not referenced directly are not included automatically. So when your (web) project references A, which uses B, B is not included.

Comment: @PatrickHofman B will also be included if the compiler can detect the dependency, but won't be included if it can't.  This is why it copies some secondary dependencies but not others.

Comment: @Jimmy: can you be more specific? I can't think of a situation where I have seen that. As far as I know B is always a reference you have to include.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I just tested it out like this: new console app references ClassLibrary1.Foo; ClassLibrary1.Foo contains a property of type ClassLibrary2.Bar; build console app and both class libraries end up in the bin folder.